# Set up an AP that indicates it is encrypted with WPA2 but in fact is open?

Tags: wifi, wpa2

I want to create an exact duplicate of an existing access point that use WPA2 AES (CCMP) for encryption so that the clients will automatcally be connected to my AP, so I used this command:

```
airbase-ng -c 11 -W 1 -Z 4 –essid MyFakeAP monO
```

However the clients throw authentication errors. What am I doing wrong, or is my idea even feasible?

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is the intended behavior. Clients won't be able to connect to your rogue AP as your AP isn't set up with the same PSK the real AP is, and clients *shouldn't* connect to a network that has the same name (SSID) but different security (unencrypted).

To answer your question, no it is not possible. Even if you manage to set up such an AP (pretty much impossible as the low level parts of Wi-Fi are handled in the NIC's firmware, so good luck getting that firmware to advertise it's broadcasting an encrypted network while in fact it isn't), the clients wouldn't be able to connect as they'll still try authenticating and will obviously fail because your AP won't be expecting the authentication frames as it's broadcasting an unencrypted network.